# Como selecionar o input com o checked marcado?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tenho este código:

```
<input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por2" value="PROC_MEM_KB" checked> MEMORIA
<input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por" value="PROC_CPU" > CPU
<input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por3" value="PROCESS_NAME"> CONTADOR
```

Como eu consigo selecionar somente o que esta `checked`?

tentei:

```
$("[name='rankeamento_por']").val())
```

porem ainda falta verificar se é checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filtre pelo tipo input e adicione o atributo `checked` para pegar o valor do item checado.

```js
console.log($("input[name='rankeamento_por']:checked").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por2" value="PROC_MEM_KB" checked> MEMORIA
<input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por" value="PROC_CPU"> CPU
<input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por3" value="PROCESS_NAME"> CONTADOR
```

Comment: Eu tentei executar o código aqui e veio `script error lineno 0 colno 0`. 10/10 lol Adoro esse report de erros.

Comment: Você copiou e mesmo assim está dando erro?

Comment: Não, eu tentei executar pelo elemento daqui da página. Disfarce a minha burrice em não informar como eu executei o código.

Answer (score 2):

Exemplo sem utilização da biblioteca jQuery:

```js
function Exibir(){
  var radio = document.getElementsByName("rankeamento_por");
  for(i=0;i<radio.length;i++){
    if(radio[i].checked){
      console.log(radio[i].value);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por2" value="PROC_MEM_KB" checked/>
  <label for="rankeamento_por2">MEMÓRIA</label>
    
  <input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por" value="PROC_CPU"/>
  <label for="rankeamento_por">CPU</label>
    
  <input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por3" value="PROCESS_NAME" />
  <label for="rankeamento_por3">CONTADOR</label>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="Exibir()">
    Exibir checkado
  </button>
</div>
```

Exemplo com jQuery:

```js
$("#exibir").on("click", function(){
  console.log(
    $("input[name='rankeamento_por']:checked").val()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por2" value="PROC_MEM_KB" checked/>
  <label for="rankeamento_por2">MEMÓRIA</label>
    
  <input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por" value="PROC_CPU"/>
  <label for="rankeamento_por">CPU</label>
    
  <input type="radio" name="rankeamento_por" id="rankeamento_por3" value="PROCESS_NAME" />
  <label for="rankeamento_por3">CONTADOR</label>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="exibir">
    Exibir checkado
  </button>
</div>
```